# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when using Interop Word document.SaveAs method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop, office-addins

Essentially I need to create a PDF archiver that saves the content of a MailItem into a PDF file.
The code is below:

```
        mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        string pdfPath = Path.Combine(fullPath + fileName + ".pdf");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
        doc.SaveAs(pdfPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

The exception happens on the .SaveAs method. What I've essentially boiled it down to, is that it has something to do with the file path, as I tried changing the file path to be shorter, to which the exception did not occur. The problem is, that it has to be in the longer file path structure. I did also consider that maybe it reached the max length of a file path (255), but from what I could tell by running pdfPath.Length, the length came out to be 81.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Surely the COMException has more detail?

Comment: @cjb110 All it says is "Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in EmailArchiverOutlook.dll" with the stacktrace just pointing to the line where the .SaveAs method happens

Comment: sorry just reread your post, the path is too long for the SaveAs command (probly due to the general historic windows limitation on path lengths).  So split it up, SaveAs to a shorter path, and then use the .NET IO File methods to move it to the final location.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you so much! I dont know why I didnt think of doing that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more, turns out that when working with file paths, you can easily use a single `/` for navigating the path, say for example: `C:/User/Desktop`.

This is the case, `UNTIL` you work with Word documents. Word doesn't appreciate single `/`, but prefers double `\\`. So, `C:/User/Desktop` becomes `C:\\User\\Desktop`.

Reason why I'm saying this, is because, while there is a File path Max length, I did not reach it.

The problem seemed to happen because there was a space in a folder name, like: `C:/User/Desktop/Folder Name`.

I then used the double backslash instead, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case I did use \\ but the path was wrong. I received the same error. Thanks